# Session timeout when using SSL for an application

Tags: session, ssl, https, jboss, session-timeout

We are currently having a jboss server which has two profiles. Each profiles have a different application, Application A and Application B are in the profiles. When we use SSL in App B there is a session timeout on App A and vice versa. Does anyone know or have any idea why this is happening.

In the server App B sends remote EJB calls to App A for data. In other words App B depends on App A. Additionally in order to startup App B App A NEEDS to be started.

We need SSL enabled for App B and this is done via the server.xml file in the IBE profile's JBOSS web deployer folder.

When using both App A and App B (both without SSL) there is no server timeout however when using App A (without SSL, as we don't use SSL for App A) and App B with SSL there is a session timeout. An example

1. Load up both App A and App B
2. Login to App A (no SSL)
3. Access a screen or do some function in App A
4. Go to App B and click on a button to do some function (SSL)
5. App B session has timed out
6. Go to app A and do another function
7. App A session has timed out

Here is the attached server.xml of Application A

```
<Server>
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />

   <!-- Use a custom version of StandardService that allows the
   connectors to be started independent of the normal lifecycle
   start to allow web apps to be deployed before starting the
   connectors.
   -->
   <Service name="jboss.web">

    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
     <Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
         maxThreads="350" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
         emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
         connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" compression="on" />

    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3"
         emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" />

      <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost">

         <!-- The JAAS based authentication and authorization realm implementation
         that is compatible with the jboss 3.2.x realm implementation.
         - certificatePrincipal : the class name of the
         org.jboss.security.auth.certs.CertificatePrincipal impl
         used for mapping X509[] cert chains to a Princpal.
         - allRolesMode : how to handle an auth-constraint with a role-name=*,
         one of strict, authOnly, strictAuthOnly
           + strict = Use the strict servlet spec interpretation which requires
           that the user have one of the web-app/security-role/role-name
           + authOnly = Allow any authenticated user
           + strictAuthOnly = Allow any authenticated user only if there are no
           web-app/security-roles
         -->
         <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossSecurityMgrRealm"
            certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
            allRolesMode="authOnly"
            />
         <!-- A subclass of JBossSecurityMgrRealm that uses the authentication
         behavior of JBossSecurityMgrRealm, but overrides the authorization
         checks to use JACC permissions with the current java.security.Policy
         to determine authorized access.
         - allRolesMode : how to handle an auth-constraint with a role-name=*,
         one of strict, authOnly, strictAuthOnly
           + strict = Use the strict servlet spec interpretation which requires
           that the user have one of the web-app/security-role/role-name
           + authOnly = Allow any authenticated user
           + strictAuthOnly = Allow any authenticated user only if there are no
           web-app/security-roles
         <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccAuthorizationRealm"
            certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
            allRolesMode="authOnly"
            />
         -->

        <Host name="localhost"
           autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false"
           configClass="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.config.JBossContextConfig"
           >

            <!-- Uncomment to enable request dumper. This Valve "logs interesting 
                 contents from the specified Request (before processing) and the 
                 corresponding Response (after processing). It is especially useful 
                 in debugging problems related to headers and cookies."
            -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve" />
            -->

            <!-- Access logger -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
                pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" 
                resolveHosts="false" />
            -->

            <!-- Uncomment to enable single sign-on across web apps
                deployed to this host. Does not provide SSO across a cluster.     

                If this valve is used, do not use the JBoss ClusteredSingleSignOn 
                valve shown below. 

                A new configuration attribute is available beginning with
                release 4.0.4:

                cookieDomain  configures the domain to which the SSO cookie
                              will be scoped (i.e. the set of hosts to
                              which the cookie will be presented).  By default
                              the cookie is scoped to "/", meaning the host
                              that presented it.  Set cookieDomain to a
                              wider domain (e.g. "xyz.com") to allow an SSO
                              to span more than one hostname.
             -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
            -->

            <!-- Uncomment to enable single sign-on across web apps
               deployed to this host AND to all other hosts in the cluster.

               If this valve is used, do not use the standard Tomcat SingleSignOn
               valve shown above.

               Valve uses a JBossCache instance to support SSO credential 
               caching and replication across the cluster.  The JBossCache 
               instance must be configured separately.  By default, the valve 
               shares a JBossCache with the service that supports HttpSession 
               replication.  See the "jboss-web-cluster-service.xml" file in the 
               server/all/deploy directory for cache configuration details.

               Besides the attributes supported by the standard Tomcat
               SingleSignOn valve (see the Tomcat docs), this version also 
               supports the following attributes:

               cookieDomain   see above

               treeCacheName  JMX ObjectName of the JBossCache MBean used to 
                              support credential caching and replication across
                              the cluster. If not set, the default value is 
                              "jboss.cache:service=TomcatClusteringCache", the 
                              standard ObjectName of the JBossCache MBean used 
                              to support session replication.
            -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.sso.ClusteredSingleSignOn" />
            -->

            <!-- Check for unclosed connections and transaction terminated checks
                 in servlets/jsps.

                 Important: The dependency on the CachedConnectionManager
                 in META-INF/jboss-service.xml must be uncommented, too
            -->
            <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve"
                cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager"
                transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" />

         </Host>

      </Engine>

   </Service>

</Server>
```

Here is the attached server.xml of Application B which has SSL enabled

```
    <Server>
      <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
      <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />

       <!-- Use a custom version of StandardService that allows the
       connectors to be started independent of the normal lifecycle
       start to allow web apps to be deployed before starting the
       connectors.
       -->
       <Service name="jboss.web">

        <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
             and responses are returned. Documentation at :
             Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
             Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
             APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
             Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
        -->
         <Connector port="8180" address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
             maxThreads="350" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
             emptySessionPath="false" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8543" acceptCount="100"
             connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" compression="on" />

        <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
             This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
             connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
             described in the APR documentation -->
        <Connector port="8543" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" connectionTimeout="20000"
                clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/application.keystore"
            keystorePass="application"
        />

        <!--
        <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                   maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
        -->

        <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8010" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3"
             emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8543" />

          <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost">

             <!-- The JAAS based authentication and authorization realm implementation
             that is compatible with the jboss 3.2.x realm implementation.
             - certificatePrincipal : the class name of the
             org.jboss.security.auth.certs.CertificatePrincipal impl
             used for mapping X509[] cert chains to a Princpal.
             - allRolesMode : how to handle an auth-constraint with a role-name=*,
             one of strict, authOnly, strictAuthOnly
               + strict = Use the strict servlet spec interpretation which requires
               that the user have one of the web-app/security-role/role-name
               + authOnly = Allow any authenticated user
               + strictAuthOnly = Allow any authenticated user only if there are no
               web-app/security-roles
             -->
             <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossSecurityMgrRealm"
                certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
                allRolesMode="authOnly"
                />
             <!-- A subclass of JBossSecurityMgrRealm that uses the authentication
             behavior of JBossSecurityMgrRealm, but overrides the authorization
             checks to use JACC permissions with the current java.security.Policy
             to determine authorized access.
             - allRolesMode : how to handle an auth-constraint with a role-name=*,
             one of strict, authOnly, strictAuthOnly
               + strict = Use the strict servlet spec interpretation which requires
               that the user have one of the web-app/security-role/role-name
               + authOnly = Allow any authenticated user
               + strictAuthOnly = Allow any authenticated user only if there are no
               web-app/security-roles
             <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccAuthorizationRealm"
                certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
                allRolesMode="authOnly"
                />
             -->

            <Host name="localhost"
               autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false"
               configClass="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.config.JBossContextConfig"
               >

                <!-- Uncomment to enable request dumper. This Valve "logs interesting 
                     contents from the specified Request (before processing) and the 
                     corresponding Response (after processing). It is especially useful 
                     in debugging problems related to headers and cookies."
                -->
                <!--
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve" />
                -->

                <!-- Access logger -->
                <!--
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                    prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
                    pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" 
                    resolveHosts="false" />
                -->

                <!-- Uncomment to enable single sign-on across web apps
                    deployed to this host. Does not provide SSO across a cluster.     

                    If this valve is used, do not use the JBoss ClusteredSingleSignOn 
                    valve shown below. 

                    A new configuration attribute is available beginning with
                    release 4.0.4:

                    cookieDomain  configures the domain to which the SSO cookie
                                  will be scoped (i.e. the set of hosts to
                                  which the cookie will be presented).  By default
                                  the cookie is scoped to "/", meaning the host
                                  that presented it.  Set cookieDomain to a
                                  wider domain (e.g. "xyz.com") to allow an SSO
                                  to span more than one hostname.
                 -->
                <!--
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
                -->

                <!-- Uncomment to enable single sign-on across web apps
                   deployed to this host AND to all other hosts in the cluster.

                   If this valve is used, do not use the standard Tomcat SingleSignOn
                   valve shown above.

                   Valve uses a JBossCache instance to support SSO credential 
                   caching and replication across the cluster.  The JBossCache 
                   instance must be configured separately.  By default, the valve 
                   shares a JBossCache with the service that supports HttpSession 
                   replication.  See the "jboss-web-cluster-service.xml" file in the 
                   server/all/deploy directory for cache configuration details.

                   Besides the attributes supported by the standard Tomcat
                   SingleSignOn valve (see the Tomcat docs), this version also 
                   supports the following attributes:

                   cookieDomain   see above

                   treeCacheName  JMX ObjectName of the JBossCache MBean used to 
                                  support credential caching and replication across
                                  the cluster. If not set, the default value is 
                                  "jboss.cache:service=TomcatClusteringCache", the 
                                  standard ObjectName of the JBossCache MBean used 
                                  to support session replication.
                -->
                <!--
                <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.sso.ClusteredSingleSignOn" />
                -->

                <!-- Check for unclosed connections and transaction terminated checks
                     in servlets/jsps.

                     Important: The dependency on the CachedConnectionManager
                     in META-INF/jboss-service.xml must be uncommented, too
                -->
                <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve"
                    cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager"
                    transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" />

             </Host>

          </Engine>

       </Service>

    </Server>
```

Regards,
Milinda

Answer (score 0):

Connection time out is set to 20 seconds. Could that be the problem?